# Python adding values to existing key

Tags: python

I have two dictionaries and I want to add them together, but one key in the first dictionary matches the second one and I want them to add up.
For example:

```
a = {'beds': 10, 'house': 2}
b = {'beds': 9}
```

and I want the final output to be

```
a = {'beds': 19, 'house': 2}
```

how can it be done?

Comment: `a['beds'] += 9` Any other questions? Note that this is something you can answer by reading the python docs or any basic tutorial.

Comment: `a['beds'] += 9`

Answer (score 0):

To add a value to an existing key, just refer to the key, then increment its value. In this case, the key is `beds`

```
>>> a = {'beds': 10, 'house': 2}
>>> a['beds'] += 9
a
{'beds': 19, 'house': 2}
```